# How is Satan considered the ruler of hell according to Christians while he himself will be tormented there?

Tags: satan, hell

So in popular Christian belief, which, afaik, is popular amongst Catholics, and Protestants, Satan is termed the king of hell and will torment his followers who will be sent there due to his deceivement forever. However, there is also a simultaneously existing concept of Satan being tormented in the lake of fire as mentioned in the following verse:

> And the devil who had deceived them was thrown into the lake of fire and sulfur where the beast and the false prophet were, and they will be tormented day and night forever and ever." - Revelation 20:10 (ESV)

How does this reconcile? Is Satan the one tormenting his followers or is he being tormented himself? If so, who is tormenting him and his followers? Are they all thrown in the said "lake of fire" or just Satan, the false Prophet, and the beast?

Do note that I am not a Christian, so please take anything that I said with a grain of salt. I would appreciate the clarifications.

Comment: Btw, I didn't find any Bible verse that stated him as the ruler of hell but this wikipedia page shreds some light on this belief: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_in_Christianity#:~:text=An%20angel%20of%20the%20abyss,also%20identified%20with%20the%20devil.

> An angel of the abyss called Abaddon, mentioned in Revelation 9:11, is described as its ruler and is often thought of as the originator of sin and an instrument of punishment. For these reasons, Abaddon is also identified with the devil.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to write a full answer, but to my knowledge Satan as the ruler of hell is a pop culture thing, like his portrayal as a red satyr with a pitchfork. Not something actually taught by any main Christian denomination.

Comment: @IsaacMiddlemiss I thought that as well previously because I believe in Islam and it has the concept of eternal damnation for Satan and his followers. However, the concept of Satan being the ruler of hell in Christianity was told to me by a few friends of mine, which really bought me to this question. When I looked up "Who is the king of hell in Christianity?" I get the wikipedia quote as the first result but when I search for Bible verses actually saying this, I get none. Instead, I get the contrary one that shows him being thrown in hell.